# Is there a way to convert nested LESS to un-nested SCSS?

Tags: sass, compilation, roots-sage

I am transfering a lot of LESS files from an my old way of developing in Wordpress to Sage 9, and the linter is going crazy. So I would love a way to convert nested LESS to un-nested SCSS that the linter will allow.

Comment: I don't think any traditional Sass compiler can help you here. You might find some sort of niesche compiler for this purpose, but I highly doubt it exists. You will probably need to do it all by hand.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Then I don't have to look any more.